# Django messages framework

Tags: django, validation

I'm looking to add `Django messages` in my form in order to display `success message` if my form is validated and `error message` if my form is not validated (missing field, data type error, ...)

My error message works perfectly well, but I don't overcome to display my success message in the next template when my form is valid.

This is my view :

```
def BirthCertificate_Form_unique_number(request) :

validity = []
submission = []
#User fill some fields
query_social_number = request.GET.get('social_number')
query_social_number_father = request.GET.get('social_number_father')
query_social_number_mother = request.GET.get('social_number_mother')

success = False

if request.method == 'POST':

    form = BirthCertificateForm2(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid() :   # Vérification sur la validité des données
        post = form.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Le formulaire a été enregistré !')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('BC_treated2', args=(messages,),kwargs={'id': post.id}))

    else:
        messages.error(request, "Le formulaire est invalide !")

elif request.method == 'GET':

    form = BirthCertificateForm2()

    parent1 = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number_father)
    parent2 = Person.objects.filter(social_number=query_social_number_mother)

    if query_social_number :
        if Person.objects.filter(social_number = query_social_number).exists() == True :

            individu = get_object_or_404(Person, social_number = query_social_number)
            messages.success(request, 'Le numéro unique existe !')

            form.fields['fk_parent1'].queryset = parent1
            form.fields['fk_parent2'].queryset = parent2
            form.fields['lastname'].initial = individu.lastname
            form.fields['firstname'].initial = individu.firstname
            form.fields['birthday'].initial = individu.birthday
            form.fields['birthcity'].initial = individu.birthcity
            form.fields['birthcountry'].initial = individu.birthcountry
            form.fields['sex'].initial = individu.sex
            form.fields['social_number'].initial = individu.social_number

        elif Person.objects.filter(social_number = query_social_number).exists() == False :

            validity = False
            messages.error(request, "Le numéro unique est invalide !")


context = {
    "form" : form,
    "validity" : validity,
    "submission" : submission

}

return render(request, 'BC_form2.html', context)
```

and in my html template :

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert {{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

How I could display the success message when my form is valid ?

**EDIT :**

My urls.py file :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^BC_accueil$', views.BirthCertificate_Home, name="BChome"),
    url(r'^formulaire$', views.BirthCertificate_Form, name = "BCform"),
    url(r'^formulaire2$', views.BirthCertificate_Form_unique_number, name = "BCform2"),
    url(r'^formulaire_traite/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.BirthCertificate_Resume, name="BC_treated"),
    url(r'^formulaire2_traite/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.BirthCertificate_Resume_unique_number, name="BC_treated2"),
    url(r'^BirthCertificate_PDF/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.BirthCertificate_PDF, name="PDF"),
    url(r'^not_found$', views.BirthCertificate_notfound, name="BCnotfound"),
]
```

Comment: It looks you haven't put the complete view in your question. Does your view return an `HttpResponse` or `render` when the form is not valid?

Comment: I added the complete view ;) My view return a HttpResponse if the form is valid, else a render if not

Comment: Why are you passing `messages` as an argument to your `reverse` function when the form is valid? That shouldn't be necessary.
+ Are you sure that you have the messages context processor set up in your settings.py?

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py` and the templates portion of your `settings.py`? That'd be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

Comment: @MuhammadSaeedArabi I added urls.py file. Settings file is good ^^
itzmeontv I already read this documentation before to question you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know one thing that, `messages` will execute only once. Why did you do

```
args=(messages, )
```

You can access those messages in `BC_treated2` without passing it as `args`

Comment: Because I tried @Mubariz solution and I forgot to delete his answer which doesn't work ^^

Comment: My problem is : When my form is valid, I have HttpRedirect to the next template, but how I can display Django message success when I have HttpRedirect ?

This is my question ^^

Comment: Do like not passing messages as arguments. Change you view for that.Then in `BC_treated2` You still get `messages` as  `from django.contrib import messages`

Comment: That means, you just add that message only like you did `messages.success(request, 'Le formulaire a été enregistré !')` . Dont pass `args=(messages)`.

Comment: Yes I removed `args=(messages)` ;)

Comment: Do a try with `MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
` in settings